# object of array not update in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have form where user can add as much as he wants documents. Each document have several inputs.
And I'm trying to get each document inputs values and put it to state as array of objects.
State should look like:

```
[
   {
      id: 'UGN2WP68P1',
      name: 'passport',
      placeIssue: 'paris'
   },
   {
      id: 'TD0KUWWIM6',
      name: 'shengen visa',
      placeIssue: 'paris'
   }
   ...
]
```

So I write a function which is called on inputs change. He check are there object with same id, if there is no object with same id he creates new and add to array, if object exist with same id then he update object:

```
const addNewDocumentObj = (id, type, val) => {
        // Get object with same id
        let docObj = addedDocsArr.filter( el => el.id === id)
        
        // If there is no object with same id, creates new one
        if (docObj.length === 0) {
            if (type === 'name'){
                let obj = {
                    id: id,
                    docId: val.id
                }
                setAddedDocsArr(addedDocsArr.concat(obj))
            } else if (type === 'placeIssue') {
                let obj = {
                    id: id,
                    placeIssue: val
                }
                setAddedDocsArr(addedDocsArr.concat(obj))
            }
        // If object exist with same id then updates with new value and adds to array
        } else {
            if (type === 'name'){
                let newObject = Object.assign(docObj, {name: val.id})
                let newArray = addedDocsArr.filter(el => el.id !== id)
                setAddedDocsArr(newArray.concat(newObject))
            } else if (type === 'placeIssue') {
                let newObject = Object.assign(docObj, {placeIssue: val})
                let newArray = addedDocsArr.filter(el => el.id !== id)
                setAddedDocsArr(newArray.concat(newObject))
            } 
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, and I can't understand why, maybe my logic is bad and there is better practise?

UPDATE:
In React debugger I noticed how state changes. If I add select document name, in state object looks like that:

```
{name: 'passport', id: 'UGN2WP68P1'}
```

If I enter document place of issue value. Then object changes and show data like that:

```
{placeIssue: 'paris', id: 'UGN2WP68P1'}
```

But result should be:

```
{name: 'passport', placeIssue: 'paris', id: 'UGN2WP68P1'}
```

So it looks like that object not updated but created new one

Comment: try change from setAddedDocsArr(addedDocsArr.concat(obj)) to 
setAddedDocsArr([...addedDocsArr,obj])

Comment: Form of object is always like : ```{
      id: 'UGN2WP68P1',
      name: 'passport',
      placeIssue: 'paris'
   }``` ? i.e. always three key value pairs? And why are you using ```val``` an an object i.e. ```val.id``` in case the type is ```placeIssue```

Comment: Yes always same. Because that functions is called every time on input change

Comment: Id field is must while submitting the form?

Comment: yes, id show that this input value belongs to same document

Comment: okay, check out the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a pretty easy way how to solve this problem. I read documentations of react forms and find multiple inputs idea [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)
So I changed my code to:

```
// Update or add information of added documents inputs
const addNewDocumentObj = (id, e, name) => {
        const newInput = addedDocsArr.map(el => {
            if(id === el.id) {
                if(name === 'name'){
                    el[name] = e.target.value
                } else if (name === 'placeIssue'){
                    el[name] = e.target.value
                }
            }
            return el
          })
          
          setAddedDocsArr(newInput);
    }

// Add new document inputs
    const addNewDocument = () => {
        let blockId = randomNumber(10, true, false)

        setAddedDocsArr([...addedDocsArr, {id: blockId, name: '', placeIssue: ''}])
    }
```

And it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like:

```
const addNewDocumentObj = (id, type, val) => {
  // Get object with same id
  let docObj = addedDocsArr.find(el => el.id === id)  
  // If there is no object with same id, creates new one
  if (!docObj) {
    docObj = { id, placeIssue: val }
    // and pushes it to addedDocsArray
    addedDocsArr.push(docObj)
  }

  if (type === 'name') {
    docObj.name = val.id
  } else if (type === 'placeIssue') {
    docObj.placeIssue = val
  }

  setAddedDocsArr(addedDocsArr)
}
```

First of all, why are you using `filter` if you are actually try to `find` something in array? Just use `find`.

Second, if object with given `id` is already exists, there is no need to filter your array and then put that object back... Just find that object in array and update it! It is already in your array! Remember that `Array` contains **references** to your objects, so when you grab your object from the `Array` and edit it, your edit the same object that `Array` have.

Last one, Idk what logic your `setAddedDocsArr` function have. In my example I assume that the only thing it does is set its argument (newArray) to the variable named `addedDocsArr`. So instead of that, in situation where object with given id is not present, I just `push` it in old array.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works partly. Now function updates object, but I had to do some changes of your suggestion. First, I have to use  `setAddedDocsArr` because this is state setter (I'm working with hooks). Second, I can't use `.push()` method, because he return number not `Array`, so I used `.concat()` method instead. But there is another problem, if I add several documents, and decide to edit first document, then in state remains only one object of first document and others disappear.

Comment: @Roman ok then maybe you should call `setAddedDocsArr(addedDocsArr)` in the end?

Comment: it doesn't work and makes no sense, because it override with empty array

Answer (score 0):

Finished App:

[image]

Implementation of Handle submit:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!uid) {
      alert("Please enter the ID");
      return;
    }
    let existingRecords = docs.filter((doc) => doc.id === uid);
    if (!existingRecords.length) {
      let newRecord = {
        id: uid,
        name: name,
        issuePlace: place
      };
      setDocs([...docs, newRecord]);
      setId("");
      setName("");
      setPlace("");
    } else {
      let unmodifiedRecords = docs.filter((doc) => doc.id !== uid);
      if (name) {
        existingRecords[0].name = name;
      }
      if (place) {
        existingRecords[0].issuePlace = place;
      }
      unmodifiedRecords.push(existingRecords[0]);
      setDocs(unmodifiedRecords);
      setId("");
      setName("");
      setPlace("");
    }

  };
```

And Here is the full finished example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([
    { id: "1", name: "passport", issuePlace: "delhi" }
  ]);
  const [uid, setId] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [place, setPlace] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!uid) {
      alert("Please enter the ID");
      return;
    }
    let existingRecords = docs.filter((doc) => doc.id === uid);
    if (!existingRecords.length) {
      let newRecord = {
        id: uid,
        name: name,
        issuePlace: place
      };
      setDocs([...docs, newRecord]);
      setId("");
      setName("");
      setPlace("");
    } else {
      let unmodifiedRecords = docs.filter((doc) => doc.id !== uid);
      if (name) {
        existingRecords[0].name = name;
      }
      if (place) {
        existingRecords[0].issuePlace = place;
      }
      unmodifiedRecords.push(existingRecords[0]);
      setDocs(unmodifiedRecords);
      setId("");
      setName("");
      setPlace("");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>ID: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                value={uid}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setId(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Name: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setName(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Isuue Place: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                value={place}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPlace(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>

      {docs.map((doc) => (
        <div className="records">
          <span>{"ID:" + doc.id + "   "}</span>
          <span>{"Name:" + doc.name + "   "}</span>
          <span>{"Issue Place:" + doc.issuePlace + "   "}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out finished example with source code at: [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-robinson-kkmt8?file=/src/App.js:0-2689)